# VLCJ setting custom library location at runtime

Tags: java, linux, jna, vlcj

I have a Java program that uses vlcj to play videos and that packages the VLC libs in the jar. At runtime, the VLC libs are extracted to the user's home, let's say path A. The normal way to indicate this path to vlcj is through the jna method:

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "A");
```

This works under Windows and MacOSX but not Linux where it throws a *UnsatisfiedLinkError*.

After some trial and error, I found that the only to get this to work under linux was by using

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=A
```

prior to execution and despite the JNA documentation, none of these worked in JVM settings:

```
-Djava.library.path=A
-Djna.library.path=A
-Djna.platform.library.path=A
```

My problem with using *LD_LIBRARY_PATH* is that it is not something I can set at runtime (can I?) which I need to do. Does anyone know of a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

I never found an ideal solution to this myself, but this is what I found during my trials with my own vlcj projects.

If you build VLC yourself on Linux you will see these warnings:

```
If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'
```

None of those things it suggests can you do from *within* your JVM, at least not without calling native code with privilege escalation.

So, in general what you are left with is: `-Djna.library.path=LIBDIR` should work; alternatively in code `System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "LIBDIR");` should also work.

In fact I just tested that with my own native library that I happen to use in my own vlcj projects and both of those approaches worked just fine.

However, it seems it is not so easy with VLC itself, probably because of the way VLC loads its plugins.

In theory, if you structure your directories correctly, the plugins should get discovered automatically so you only need to point `jna.library.path` to the directory that contains the `libvlc` and `libvlccore` shared objects. In my build of VLC, the directory structure looks like this:

```
VLCDIR
VLCDIR/libvlc.so
VLCDIR/libvlc.so.5
VLCDIR/libvlc.so.5.4.0
VLCDIR/libvlccore.so
VLCDIR/libvlccore.so.7.0.0
VLCDIR/vlc/plugins
```

If this still fails then, again in theory, you can set the `VLC_PLUGIN_PATH` environment variable to point to the directory containing the VLC plugins. The problem is that this must be set for the native process, it will *not* work if you set it as a system property from inside your Java application.

I can only really suggest you generate a shell-script file that sets up the environment correctly when you install your application, or if you want to do it programmatically inside the JVM you could maybe have a bootstrap application that prepares the native environment and then kicks off a new Java process for your actual application - but it's messy to do things that way.

What I have also seen on Linux is that the library paths seem "baked in" to the ".so" files, and you can't just copy those files anywhere and still expect it to work. That is why you must use e.g. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `libtool` or one of the other proposed solutions.

And this does not even touch on what you do with all the other libraries that VLC and its plugins may depend on at run-time - are you going to ship all those too?

My recommendation really is just to have the user install VLC first, or have your installer application install VLC first, by using the OS native package installation commands. Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Strangely, the problem persists, even though I respected the hierarchy. It seems the jna.library.path property is not "passed on" for loading beyond libvlc.so (remember in my question, LD_LIBRARY_PATH *does* work so it boils down to how the libraries cascade). The problem with using installed versions is that you can't guarantee the compatibility with the vlcj you are shipping.

Comment: JNA doesn't load VLC's plugins; you would need to reconfigure VLC so that it alters the path *it* uses to load its plugins.

Comment: There's a similar question here: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=119693#p404962 - the advice there is to put the plugins in a subdirectory named "plugins" under the directory that contains the libvlccore shared library.